# SQL Date Help Needed

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
-- DELETE Current month and Month - 1 records from MonthlyTbl
 DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_SDW_MONTHLY_AS
 WHERE [Month Number] > MONTH(GETDATE()) - 2
 AND [Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

The query does not appear to be deleting the records from December 2013, can you help me fix this?

Comment: You should provide some sample data. `select MONTH(GETDATE()) - 2` returns `-1` currently as we're in January.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so, what version? Have you checked your values in your where clause by doing `Select year(getdate())` and `select month(getdate())`? That might help you understand why certain records wouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Year getdate() would return 2014 for one thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = getdate() 

DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_SDW_MONTHLY_AS
WHERE 
100 * [Year] + [Month Number] >= 
(
100 * datepart(YEAR, dateadd(DAY, - datepart(DAY, @dt) - 1, @dt)) + 
datepart(MONTH, dateadd(DAY, - datepart(DAY, @dt) - 1, @dt))
)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I dont want to use hard coded dates as this is a rolling task, and delete the previous 2 months each month.

Comment: @user3228755 OK, I see, you should have mentioned that. On which date of the month will you run it?

Comment: This is a task that updates around about 4 times per day every day (it takes live data from another source and I only ever want the most current.

Comment: @user3228755 If it runs now which data do you need deleted? From 11/1 onwards or from 12/1 onwards? Is this SQL Server?

Comment: Peter thanks for your support. I only ever want to delete the last 2 months worth of data, IE if it was 12/2/2014 I only want it to delete February 2014 and January 2014 or in the case at the moment Delete January 2014 and December 2013.

Comment: OK, answer updated. Check it out and test it with various @dt values. It should be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter, appreciate it.

Comment: NP. But ideally you should have posted all this information which we clarified here in the original question text. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MONTH number and YEAR number.

Use the dates instead.

```
 DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_SDW_MONTHLY_AS
 WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Bobby thanks for this I dont have a date column, I have a Year column and a month column only. I want to try and avoid hard coding dates in as this will need to roll on each month only deleting the 2 previous months.